# Linq with entity - DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType. Parameter name: input

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get the taxcode, taxname and taxrate as list using linq. But it's showing the following error: 
   **"DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
      Parameter name: input"**

**Table Data**

Code | Name  |   Rate

1     Tax1       4

1     Tax1.2     7

2     Tax2       5

3     Tax3       2

**Need Output**

Code | Name   |  Rate

2     Tax2       5

3     Tax3       2

Condition : Retrieve the details if the number of code is one.

```
UAAPPEntities context;
context=new UAAPPEntities();
var x = from txs in context.OTAXs 
        where txs.Code.Count()<=1 
        select new TaxModel{ taxCode=txs.Code, taxName=txs.Name,taxRate=txs.Rate.Value };                        
taxList = x.ToList();
return taxList;
```

Comment: code is a field in otax table.

Comment: So what does it mean to say `txs.Code.Count`?

Comment: I have edited the question , Please refer the question

Comment: My question is still relevant, what are you trying to do when you say `txs.Code.Count()<=1`?

Comment: @DavidG is on the right track. `The problem is at this txs.Code.Count() <=1 `

Comment: @Indra specify what is the Code.Count() you are trying to get.. is it a list of data of another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution using the following query:

```
var x = from t1 in context.OTAXs
                    group t1.Code by new { t1.Code } into g
                    where g.Count()<=1
                    join txs in context.OTAXs on g.Key.Code equals txs.Code
                    select new TaxModel { taxCode = txs.Code, taxName = txs.Code, description = txs.Code, taxRate = txs.Rate.Value };
```

Happy coding..

Thanks,
Indhu.